# how to read XML with ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

Is there a way to read xml with ruby and easily get attributes? Iterating maybe?

```
<people>
    <john id=1></john>
    <Mary id=2></Mary>
</people>
```

I would like to look at Mary or Johns id's. (John['id']?)

Comment: Take a look at [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Comment: any particular methods? documentation is huge...

Comment: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html

Comment: The documentation is good, but you really should take the time to read [the tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials), then start experimenting. The tutorials will show you the handful of methods needed to do 99% of the work you'll want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_xml_xslt.htm).

sample code from the above link:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

xmlfile = File.new("movies.xml")
xmldoc = Document.new(xmlfile)

# Now get the root element
root = xmldoc.root
puts "Root element : " + root.attributes["shelf"]

# This will output all the movie titles.
xmldoc.elements.each("collection/movie"){ 
   |e| puts "Movie Title : " + e.attributes["title"] 
}
```

Comment: nice, but when i'm iterating through lets say movie types, its gonna also iterate through movies, since they are parents. how do i know whether 'e' is a movie or a type?

Comment: If you are iterating on `xmldoc.elements.each("collection/movie/type") `, `e` will be movie type, `e` will the element on which you are iterating and you have provided it in `each`.

Answer (score 2):

First, your XML is malformed:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<people>
    <john id=1></john>
    <Mary id=2></Mary>
</people>
EOT

doc.errors 
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: AttValue: " or ' expected>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: attributes construct error>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Couldn't find end of Start Tag john line 2>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: people line 1 and john>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document>]
```

In other words, the value for the `id` in both tags needs to be wrapped in single or double quotes.

After fixing that:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<people>
    <john id="1"></john>
    <Mary id="2"></Mary>
</people>
EOT

doc.at('john')['id'] # => "1"
doc.at('Mary')['id'] # => "2"
```

Or:

```
doc.search('john, Mary').map{ |n| n['id'] } # => ["1", "2"]
```

Read [the tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) for a jump-start.